# Redshift Avg not returning decimals

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I can't figure out how to return a decimal in an average calculation.

I have:

```sql
select
    r_i_flag,
    mr_age_bucket,
    count(request_id) as sum_requests,
    avg(age_of_mr_days) as avg_age_of_mr_days,
    median(age_of_mr_days) as median_age_of_mr_days
from
    together
group by
    1,
    2
order by
    1 desc,
    2
```

I've tried casting the mr_age_bucket as numeric, tried casting the avg/median as numeric, as a decimal, using to_number, but I'm just getting rounded numbers:

| r_i_flag | mr_age_bucket | sum_requests | avg_age_of_mr_days | median_age_of_mr_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Retail | <7 days | 29 | 1 | 1 |
| Retail | >7 Days | 107 | 46 | 30 |
| Institutional | <7 days | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| Institutional | >7 Days | 13 | 45 | 29 |

I feel like this is a super silly thing but I can't figure it out. How do I return a non-rounded number? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try casting the argument to `avg` (that is, `age_of_mr_days`) to the type & precision that you want its result to be?

Comment: Yes, I did try that. It is still returning a whole number.

Comment: How are you running this query? For example, what SQL client are you using? Sometimes the clients modify the information that is returned.

Comment: I think John is on to it.  I suspect what you're seeing ia something, somewhere, rounding off when it comes to *display* the number.  BTW, can you post the DDL of the table you're using?  I'd like to see the original data types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is a data type passed into AVG, just dividing it with 1.0 will do the trick. Casting to `DOUBLE PRECISION` or `REAL` will also work

```sql
select
    r_i_flag,
    mr_age_bucket,
    count(request_id) as sum_requests,
    avg(age_of_mr_days / 1.0) as avg_age_of_mr_days,
    avg(age_of_mr_days::double precision),
    avg(age_of_mr_days::real),
    median(age_of_mr_days) as median_age_of_mr_days

from
    together
group by
    1,
    2
order by
    1 desc,
    2
```

Comment: The docs says `AVG` returns `numeric` unless a float/double, then you get `float8`.  I would expect the original code to be returning a `numeric` and so be obtaining a fractional part - it is not clear to me why it is not.  Dividing by 1.0 is I guess converting to a float, and so now the return type is a `float8`.  This changes the characteristics of the number being returned, which should be mentioned.

Comment: Hopefully this is it, though they did tell me they tried casting the argument and it didn't help.

Comment: Casting as `real` did the trick. Thank you!